# jQuery datetimepicker use current format

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

How can I set the datetimepicker format display always the current culture?
I can find many tutorials where the format is set directly, as in datetimepicker [docu](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/):

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  format:'DD.MM.YYYY h:mm a',
  formatTime:'h:mm a',
  formatDate:'DD.MM.YYYY'
});
```

What I want is that every user can see the date with his current date format settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
format: 'd.m.Y H:i'
```

solves the issue.